# How do I create a static library which automatically links to a dynamic library?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, unix-ar, .a

I maintain our in-house infrastructure library - lets call it `libcluracan`. This library has to be statically linked because it doesn't exist on outside computers where the code is used.

This means that instead of creating a `libcluracan.so` file using the linker I create a `libcluracan.a` file using the `ar` command

Now I'm trying to add some new functionality to `libcluracan`, but it requires linking with an outside library - specifically `-lfltk`, but the specifics aren't important. What is important is that I can assume the outside computers have this library (and any other publicly available library I need).

The biggest problem is that I can't change how the in-house programmers compile (well, link) their code.

Had we been using a dynamic `libcluracan.so` library I'd just add `-lfltk` to the linker and forget about it - the programmers would continue to link with `-lcluracan` and get `-lfltk` automatically.

I need to find a way to do the same thing with our static `libcluracan.a` library.

**TL;DR**

Is there a way to create a static `.a` library that automatically links to another dynamic `.so` library when used?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you just include the new header files in your program and compile it statically, then it should automatically search for the dynamic library on execution. I have done this with Windows. My Qt application is being compiled statically but I am linking it with a new DLL on program execution.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - this works, but it requires the programmers using the library to link with `-lfltk` as well, or they'd get "undefined symbol" errors on linking. And unfortunately I can't change how they link their code. :(

Comment: So you want to embed that dynamic library in your static executable as well? I don't know whether that would be possible without recompiling that new library statically.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal - I don't want to embed `-lfltk` in the executable. I want the executable to *dynamically* link to `-lfltk`, but without the programmers adding the `-lfltk` flag to their linker command. I want that when they link with `libcluracan.a` it automatically adds the `-lfltk` (same as is possible had `libcluracan` been a dynamic library)

Comment: I do not believe gcc supports automatic linking.

Comment: @drescherjm - well, just tried it again with dynamic linking and it works. The problem is with static linking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The biggest problem is that I can't change how the in-house programmers compile (well, link) their code.

That is *indeed* a big problem. Your in-house programmers should be using `make` (or a similar automated build system), and the change would be trivial.

There is no way to achieve what you want on an arbitrary UNIX system.

IF you are using GNU toolchain, and in particular GNU-ld or `gold`, THEN you can achieve what you want by linking with `libcluracan.so`, where `libcluracan.so` is not a shared library, but a linker script, which looks like this:

```
GROUP ( libcluracan.a libfltk.so )
```

Comment: "Your in-house programmers should be using make...and the change would be trivial" actually the change won't be trivial because we'd have to change all the Makefiles of all the different projects (hundreds at least). And we'll need to do that everytime we change the dependencies of the library. The linker script sounds great though! Do I put it in the "normal" library path for shared objects?